# Converting float64 column to int column

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-science

Notice that ProviderID, Vender and PCP in df_claims are float strings (Ex. 12231.0), which isn't accurate representation. These columns are ID's for respective entities, and ideally should be int (Ex. 12231). Convert these columns to int, handling the missing values separately.

This is my question in the assignment.

[display(df_claim)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO0QD.png)

So, I use astype to convert datatype.

```
df_claim['ProviderID'] = df_claim['ProviderID'].fillna(0)

df_claim['ProviderID'] = df_claim['ProviderID'].astype('int64')

df_claim['ProviderID'] = df_claim['ProviderID'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

[after add the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeZXU.png)

Nothing is changed.

I tried astype(int), astype('int), astype(np.int), astype('int64').
But noting of those work.

I want convert whole values in column 'ProviderID' to integer without any decimal.

Comment: np.nan is a float value, so when replacing 0 with np.nan you are casting the values back to float. If you want the column to be of type int you have to use another value as missing, like -999 for instance

Comment: Or you could replace 0 with None which seems reasonable as presumably it means there is no ProviderID.